# Per seat license for pure javascript libraries

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I have built a pure browser-side javascript UI library and I would like to sell it to companies so that they can use it on their internal websites. And I would like the pricing to be based on the number of people who use the library (either development or client).

I am thinking there is no way to enforce that the number of users is limited without providing a webserver myself. Is that technically correct? What do companies that sell javascript libraries typically do?

Comment: @meagar: I meant I could make something server-side that at least could check IP addresses or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am thinking there is no way to enforce that the number of users is limited without providing a webserver myself

No, even if you provided the web server, you couldn't prevent people from stealing the JavaScript and running it on a *different* server for as many people as they want. There are no *technical* means available to you to enforce this, it's fundamentally impossible.

> Is that technically correct? What do companies that sell javascript libraries typically do?

No; typically they *don't sell JavaScript libraries*, because they know there are a million free alternatives which are *better* than their for-profit option and have entire communities of developers contributing to them.

If you really, *really* want to sell this, your best bet is to charge a fee for using the library in commercial products, and make it free to use in all other cases.

Comment: Selling support is also another option

Comment: Right, that's what I expected. Thanks